# Changing into new window

Tags: java, swing, listener, cardlayout

What is an efficient method to have a window change into a different window? When the user presses the next button, I would want it to perform another method that would create this second window. What is the appropriate listener class for this scenario?

Comment: please go through your questions and accept answers on them that were correct.  This will encourage people to answer questions that you have in the future.

Comment: From the tutorials, I'm aware that one must add a listener to the object i care about and create an inner class to make it do stuff. The listeners, im noticing, has to fit the situation. (labellistener to change label or colorlistener to change color) That is as far as my book takes me. It doensn't quite mention window transition.

Comment: *"..(labellistener to change label or colorlistener to change color) That is as far as my book takes me."*  Take that book to the fireplace and drop it in.  There is no such thing as a 'labellistener' or 'colorlistener' in the J2SE, and listeners are already defined for most of the things you would need to listen to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example scenario for your question:

You may have a `JFrame` which is the starting point of your application, i.e. having single instance, main method, general initialization of components etc. You say you want to *change windows*. Let these windows be different `JPanel` objects that each of them are assigned to operate on different tasks. You can add these panels to your main frame. And changing these panels upon certain conditions will make your application capable of *navigating* between these panels/windows as well. So how to make this happen? Take a look at `CardLayout` and use it to navigate between your predefined panels on their container frame.

> What is the appropriate listener class for this scenario?

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9371460/544983), I have demonstrated `CardLayout` usage via `ActionListener`.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the appropriate listener class for this scenario?

An [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html).  See the links already provided in comments, for how to use one.