# Java Swing Card Layout change the displayed Panel?

Tags: java, swing, layout, panel

so I have this jFrame with a Panel.
Inside that panel there are two more panels and the layout is set to cards.
Inside one of those two panels there is a button.
How can I change the panel thats being displayed when that button is pressed?

Comment: By adding an ActionListener to that JButton that requests that the CardLayout do the swap. I assume that you've read the CardLayout tutorial and if so, there's not much more we can tell you than this given the scant information that you've provided. If you need more help, consider giving more detail.

Comment: there are similar questions in stackoverflow.com, search the site then post your question i suggest. http://stackoverflow.com/q/9371460/544983

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code snippet, hope the comments might help you understand the sequence.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/* Here we are first declaring our class that will act as the
 * base for other panels or in other terms the base for CardLayout.
 */

public class CardLayoutTest
{
    private static final String CARD_JBUTTON =  "Card JButton";
    private static final String CARD_JTEXTFIELD = "Card JTextField";    
    private static final String CARD_JRADIOBUTTON = "Card JRadioButton";

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Card Layout Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // This JPanel is the base for CardLayout for other JPanels.
        final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setLayout(new CardLayout(20, 20));

        /* Here we be making objects of the Window Series classes
         * so that, each one of them can be added to the JPanel 
         * having CardLayout. 
         */
        Window1 win1 = new Window1();
        contentPane.add(win1, CARD_JBUTTON);
        Window2 win2 = new Window2();
        contentPane.add(win2, CARD_JTEXTFIELD);
        Window3 win3 = new Window3();
        contentPane.add(win3, CARD_JRADIOBUTTON);

        /* We need two JButtons to go to the next Card
         * or come back to the previous Card, as and when
         * desired by the User.
         */
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(); 
        final JButton previousButton = new JButton("PREVIOUS");
        previousButton.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        previousButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        final JButton nextButton = new JButton("NEXT");
        nextButton.setBackground(Color.RED);
        nextButton.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        buttonPanel.add(previousButton);
        buttonPanel.add(nextButton);

        /* Adding the ActionListeners to the JButton,
         * so that the user can see the next Card or
         * come back to the previous Card, as desired.
         */
        previousButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) contentPane.getLayout();
                cardLayout.previous(contentPane);
            }
        });
        nextButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                CardLayout cardLayout = (CardLayout) contentPane.getLayout();
                cardLayout.next(contentPane);   
            }
        });

        // Adding the contentPane (JPanel) and buttonPanel to JFrame.
        frame.add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
} 

class Window1 extends JPanel
{
    /*
     * Here this is our first Card of CardLayout, which will
     * be added to the contentPane object of JPanel, which
     * has the LayoutManager set to CardLayout.
     * This card consists of Two JButtons.
     */  
    private ActionListener action;

    public Window1() 
    {
        init();
    }

    private void init() 
    {
        final JButton clickButton = new JButton("CLICK ME");
        final JButton dontClickButton = new JButton("DON\'T CLICK ME");     

        action = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                if (ae.getSource() == clickButton)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello there dude!"
                                                , "Right Button", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
                else if (ae.getSource() == dontClickButton)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "I told you not to click me!"
                                                        , "Wrong Button", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
            }
        };

        clickButton.addActionListener(action);
        dontClickButton.addActionListener(action);

        add(clickButton);
        add(dontClickButton);
    }
}

class Window2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener 
{
    /*
     * Here this is our second Card of CardLayout, which will
     * be added to the contentPane object of JPanel, which
     * has the LayoutManager set to CardLayout.
     * This card consists of a JLabel and a  JTextField
     * with GridLayout.
     */  

    private JTextField textField;

    public Window2() 
    {
        init();
    }

    private void init() 
    {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Your Name : ");
        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.addActionListener(this);

        add(userLabel);
        add(textField);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {            
        if (textField.getDocument().getLength() > 0)
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Name is : " + textField.getText()
                                                                            , "User\'s Name : ", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    }
}

class Window3 extends JPanel
{
    /*
     * Here this is our third Card of CardLayout, which will
     * be added to the contentPane object of JPanel, which
     * has the LayoutManager set to CardLayout.
     * This card consists of Two JLabels and two JCheckBox
     * with GridLayout.
     */  
    private ActionListener state;

    public Window3()
    {
        init();
    }

    public void init()
    {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        JLabel maleLabel = new JLabel("MALE", JLabel.CENTER);
        final JCheckBox maleBox = new JCheckBox();
        JLabel femaleLabel = new JLabel("FEMALE", JLabel.CENTER);
        final JCheckBox femaleBox = new JCheckBox();

        state = new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                if (maleBox == (JCheckBox) ae.getSource())
                {
                    femaleBox.setSelected(false);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congrats you are a Male"
                                                , "Gender : ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);                            
                }
                else if (femaleBox == (JCheckBox) ae.getSource())
                {
                    maleBox.setSelected(false);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congrats you are a Female"
                                            , "Gender : ", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);                        
                }
            }
        };

        maleBox.addActionListener(state);
        femaleBox.addActionListener(state);
        add(maleLabel);
        add(maleBox);
        add(femaleLabel);
        add(femaleBox);
    }
}
```

Comment: this example (on this forum) you can use 3-5 times per once day +1

Comment: @mKorbel : Too true, I just realized, I had posted this code once before somewhere. I was reading somethings, and suddenly this question came and I posted without thinking that, that the answer to this thing has been posted a number of times before on SO :-)

Comment: Thanks that helped!
I tried adding the actionListener to the button in one of of the panels but when I try to get the panel's layout from the main form it says "non static variable contentPane cannot be referenced from a static context". Any ideas?

Comment: @Dangerosking : Your contentPane variable is not static, and seems like you are using it as an instance variable i.e. it's a variable defined for the class, and you are using it inside your method() which is static. To resolve this either make and object of your class then refer to your contentPane by, classObject.contentPane or you can make your contentPane as static like (static JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();). That will do

Comment: I made contentPane static and I don't get any errors now, however when I press the button nothing happens, but if I press it twice the other Panel shows as its supposed to

Comment: @Dangerosking : May you please post your code to your question, I can comment out the part that is creating problems in that then. Just edit your question to post your code in that, so that I can see what is making your program not work as expected. :-)

Comment: lol one of the action listeners was inside another changed it, works perfectly now, thanks :D

Comment: Hehe , Your Welcome and keep Smiling :-)