# addActionListener on panel. How to map to main frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have 2 panel (2 class, extends from JPanel), 1 frame (1 class, extends from JFrame)

My first panel - WelcomePanel:

```
package caro;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class WelcomePanel extends JPanel {

    public WelcomePanel() {

        ImageIcon logoImage = new ImageIcon("/home/khanhpq/logo.png");
        JButton playButton = new JButton("Play");
        JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

        JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel(logoImage);

        add(imageLabel);
        add(playButton);
        add(exitButton);

        playButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



            }
        });

        exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure ?", "Warning", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);               
                if(option == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

My second panel - BoardPanel:

```
package caro;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BoardPanel extends JPanel {    

    public BoardPanel() {

        JPanel boardPanel = new JPanel();

        Board board = new Board();

        CellButton cellButton[] = new CellButton[144];

        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(12, 12);     
        boardPanel.setLayout(gridLayout);       

        for (int i = 0; i < 144; i++) {         
                cellButton[i] = new CellButton();               
                boardPanel.add(cellButton[i]);              
        }

    }

}
```

My main frame - MainFrame

```
package caro;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    public MainFrame() {
        add(new WelcomePanel());
        setSize(360, 380);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame startFrame = new MainFrame();
    }

}
```

My question: Help me write code, addActionListener on buttons of panels (material example). When i press play button (of WelcomePanel), WelcomePanel is hidden and BoardPanel is show. And, when i exit BoardPanel (close button is pressed, or click x button), WelcomePanel is showed.
My friend recommend use Message and Handle, but I don't know. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: 1) For many components in one space, use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as seen in this [short example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556). 2) Don't extend frame or other top level containers.  Instead create & use an instance of one.  The same for `JPanel` in this case, the code is not changing or adding functionality to the panel, so just use (2x) an instance `JPanel`.

Comment: You can use a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), as shown in this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9425769/1057230)

Answer (score 2):

Its better to declare dependencies (Component like buttons, panels, etc...) as fields. In this way they are visible for a third class that is the Controller of them. In next examaple I make MainFrame controlling itself, just an example. Read about Presentation patterns for better pratices.

WelcomePanel.java

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class WelcomePanel extends JPanel {

    /* Declare your dependecies as fields,
     * so you can hold a reference.
     */
    ImageIcon logoImage;
    JButton playButton;
    JButton exitButton;
    JLabel imageLabel;

    public WelcomePanel() {

        logoImage = new ImageIcon("/home/khanhpq/logo.png");
        playButton = new JButton("Play");
        exitButton = new JButton("Exit");
        imageLabel = new JLabel(logoImage);

        add(imageLabel);
        add(playButton);
        add(exitButton);

    }

}
```

BoardPanel.java

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class BoardPanel extends JPanel {

    /* Declare your dependecies as fields,
     * so you can hold a reference.
     */
    JButton closeButton;

    public BoardPanel() {
        closeButton = new JButton();
        add(closeButton);

    }
}
```

MainFrame.java

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    /* Declare your dependecies as fields,
     * so you can hold a reference.
     */
    WelcomePanel welcomePanel;
    BoardPanel boardPanel;

    public MainFrame() {
        welcomePanel = new WelcomePanel();
        boardPanel = new BoardPanel();

        add(welcomePanel);
        add(boardPanel);

        boardPanel.setVisible(false);

        boardPanel.closeButton.addActionListener(this);
        welcomePanel.playButton.addActionListener(this);

        setSize(360, 380);
    }

    /**
     * This class is the controller.
     */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(boardPanel.closeButton)) {
            welcomePanel.setVisible(false);
            boardPanel.setVisible(true);
        } else if (e.getSource().equals(welcomePanel.playButton)) {
            welcomePanel.setVisible(true);
            boardPanel.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MainFrame startFrame = new MainFrame();
                startFrame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: But, when run your code. Only show 1 windows and nothing. Please help me fix your code. Thanks.

Comment: To fix the second empty frame problem: "add" the second frame before you tell it to become visible (not pretty, but it works)