# Netbeans GUI builder - to show a panel over another panel

Tags: java, swing, layout, netbeans

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I stack/overlay jPanels in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371460/how-can-i-stack-overlay-jpanels-in-java)

I want to create a panel over another so that after clicking next button from first panel second panel gets open above it in same frame.

How can I do this using Netbeans GUI builder?

Answer (score 3):

What you *really* want is a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) , Have a look at this : [How to Use CardLayout.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Matisse feature of Netbeans, which uses GroupLayout, you may have to write some code to overcome your problem. 
While creating your GUI keep both the panels on top of each other, keep the default visibility of your 2nd panel as false. Then when the button is clicked, set the 1st panel's visibility to false and change the 2nd panel's visibility to true.