# JFrames and JPanels

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

Hmm, I appear to be running into an odd problem here, that I believe I once solved, but for the life of me cannot remember. I have a JFrame, with a JPanel in it, and I attempt to add another JPanel to the existing JPanel. However, nothing shows up. I've placed with calling setVisible() & repaint(), but still a no go.

Anyone care to take a crack at this?

Here's my code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package bakarangerx;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Ryan
 */
public class MainForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form MainForm
     */
    public MainForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        FileChooser_Open = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();
        FileChooser_Save = new javax.swing.JFileChooser();
        Panel_Main = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        MenuItem_New = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        MenuItem_Open = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        MenuItem_Save = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        FileChooser_Open.setDialogTitle("Open BakaRangerX File...");
        FileChooser_Open.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                FileChooser_OpenMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Panel_Main.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout());

        jMenu1.setText("File");

        MenuItem_New.setText("New");
        MenuItem_New.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                MenuItem_NewMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(MenuItem_New);

        MenuItem_Open.setText("Open");
        MenuItem_Open.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                MenuItem_OpenMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        MenuItem_Open.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                MenuItem_OpenActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(MenuItem_Open);

        MenuItem_Save.setText("Save");
        MenuItem_Save.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                MenuItem_SaveMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jMenu1.add(MenuItem_Save);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Edit");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(Panel_Main, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 788, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(Panel_Main, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 459, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void MenuItem_OpenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        //FileChooser_Open.showOpenDialog(this);
        ExaminerPanel newPanel = new ExaminerPanel();
        newPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        newPanel.setVisible(true);
        Panel_Main.setVisible(true);
        Panel_Main.add(newPanel);
        newPanel.repaint();
        Panel_Main.repaint();
        this.repaint();

    }                                             

    private void MenuItem_NewMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                         

    private void MenuItem_SaveMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void MenuItem_OpenMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                          

    private void FileChooser_OpenMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                              
        if(!FileChooser_Open.getSelectedFile().equals(null)) 
        {



        }
    }                                             

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JFileChooser FileChooser_Open;
    private javax.swing.JFileChooser FileChooser_Save;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem MenuItem_New;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem MenuItem_Open;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem MenuItem_Save;
    private javax.swing.JPanel Panel_Main;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    // End of variables declaration
}




/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package bakarangerx;

/**
 *
 * @author Ryan
 */
public class ExaminerPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form Examiner
     */
    public ExaminerPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        Button_Previous = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Button_Next = new javax.swing.JButton();
        Button_Check = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        TextArea_CorrectAnswer = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        TextArea_Question = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane3 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        TextArea_Answer = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel11 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel13 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel14 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel15 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        jLabel1.setText("Question");

        jLabel2.setText("Correct Answer");

        Button_Previous.setText("Previous");

        Button_Next.setText("Next");

        Button_Check.setText("Check");

        jLabel3.setText("Wrong");

        jLabel4.setText("Right");

        TextArea_CorrectAnswer.setColumns(20);
        TextArea_CorrectAnswer.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(TextArea_CorrectAnswer);

        TextArea_Question.setColumns(20);
        TextArea_Question.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(TextArea_Question);

        jLabel5.setText("Answer");

        TextArea_Answer.setColumns(20);
        TextArea_Answer.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane3.setViewportView(TextArea_Answer);

        jLabel6.setText("Total Time");

        jLabel7.setText("Time");

        jLabel8.setText("jLabel8");

        jLabel9.setText("jLabel9");

        jLabel10.setText("jLabel10");

        jLabel11.setText("jLabel11");

        jLabel12.setText("jLabel12");

        jLabel13.setText("Grade");

        jLabel14.setText("jLabel14");

        jLabel15.setText("%");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel13)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel12)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel9)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(jLabel4)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel11)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel7)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel10))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                .addGap(57, 57, 57)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(Button_Previous)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(Button_Next))
                                    .addComponent(jScrollPane3)))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addComponent(Button_Check)))
                        .addGap(19, 19, 19))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel6)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jLabel8)
                        .addGap(76, 76, 76)))
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(318, 318, 318)
                .addComponent(jLabel15)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel14)
                .addContainerGap(430, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8))
                .addGap(16, 16, 16)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel14)
                    .addComponent(jLabel15))
                .addGap(17, 17, 17)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9)
                    .addComponent(jLabel10)
                    .addComponent(jLabel11)
                    .addComponent(jLabel12)
                    .addComponent(jLabel13))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                        .addComponent(Button_Check)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(Button_Next)
                            .addComponent(Button_Previous)))
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton Button_Check;
    private javax.swing.JButton Button_Next;
    private javax.swing.JButton Button_Previous;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea TextArea_Answer;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea TextArea_CorrectAnswer;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea TextArea_Question;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel10;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel11;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel12;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel13;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel14;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel15;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: Try using imports instead of the full name. Also remove the IDE generated comments.

Comment: It would be easier if you would pare down this code to the smallest example that demonstrates your problem, if you put that little bit of effort into the snippet you'll get a much faster and better answer.

Comment: That's more than 200 lines of code. There is no way anyone is going to read it. If you can povide a concise code of what you are doing and the problem, we can try...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `Component#validate` instead

```
//FileChooser_Open.showOpenDialog(this);
ExaminerPanel newPanel = new ExaminerPanel();
Panel_Main.add(newPanel);
Panel_Main.validate();
Panel_Main.repaint();
```

Comment: Swing can sometimes be a little to clever for it self and sometimes needs a little "nudge".  Adding a component to a container will "invalidate" that container, but unless that triggers some kind of cascade back up the container hierarchy, it may not trigger a re-validation of that component. `validate` *Validating a container means laying out its subcomponents* and `repaint` just asks that the repaint manager schedule a repaint event for this container

Answer (score 6):

Use `CardLayout` to add multiple `JPanel` objects to your frame. With `CardLayout` you will be able to make one panel visible at any time.

Here is a simple demo of CardLayout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9377623/544983

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to achieve with two panels? I copied your code in eclipse, just because it was opened, as they said, the code is long. What I see is a single frame+panel with a menu. I understand that you tied up showing the panel to the "open" menu command, so maybe you need to add a validate to your second panel call if you want to lay it over the first one? Or resort to layouts if you do something trickier.

Comment: Honestly, all I was trying to do was just load one panel into the other. I wasn't aware that any trickery was needed to get it to display, but I am at a loss as to why it will not.

Comment: I think MadProgrammer gave a really good explanation for (re)validating your component. I was rather asking what is your intent with this panels, because layouts, in my opinion, is better style to handle this issue.